# Can javascript read webpage?

Tags: javascript, node.js

can my page Javascript read same page which itself is loaded? Like other parts of page are dynamically loaded by other provider. I have tried many things, google as well, but now I am in doubt that it is posible. Or it is.

Thank You!

Comment: Most probably, although it's not clear what exactly you want to do

Comment: I would like to read adds in the same page. Like links URL of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page has loaded and the javascript you are running is client-side (which it should be), you should be able to access everything on the page via the document object. I would advise reading about the DOM to familiarise yourself with this.

EDIT: removed link

Comment: remove the link to w3schools. they're not a reliable reference and in fact they're often full of errors and misleading information. I'm sure you can find plenty of other resources to link to.

Comment: also this is a clue! :) at least a have this info.

Answer (score 0):

Server side code (whether written in JavaScript or otherwise) is not capable of determining the final rendering of the page in the user's browser.

You could build the entire page yourself (and you could use a headless browser, like PhantomJS, to do it) but that could give different results to a visitor's as you would have a different set of cookies, a different source IP address, and so on.